# How to specify a typeclass instance?

Tags: haskell, instance, typeclass

I have a (fairly) legitimate case where there are two type instance implementations, and I want to specify a default one. After noting that doing modular arithmetic with `Int` types resulted in lots of hash collisions, I want to try GHC's Int64. I have the following code:

```
class Hashable64 a where
    hash64 :: a -> Int64

instance Hashable64 a => Hashable a where
    hash = fromInteger . toInteger . hash64

instance Hashable64 a => Hashable64 [a] where
    hash64 = foldl1 (\x y -> x + 22636946317 * y) . map hash64
```

and an instance `Hashable64 Char`, which thus results in two implementations for `Hashable String`, namely:

- The one defined in `Data.Hashable`.
- Noting that it is an `Hashable64` instance, then converting to a regular `Int` for an instance of `Data.Hashable`.

The second code path may be better because it performs hashing with `Int64`s. **Can I specify to use this derivation of the instance Hashable String**?

#### Edit 1

Sorry, I forgot to add I have already tried the overlapping instances thing; perhaps I'm just not implementing it correctly? The documentation for overlapping instances says it works when one instance is more specific. But when I try to add a specific instance for `Hashable String`, the situation doesn't improve. Full code at [ http://pastebin.com/9fP6LUX2 ] (sorry for the superfluous default header).

```
instance Hashable String where
    hash x = hash (hash64 x)
```

I get

```
Matching instances:
  instance (Hashable a) => Hashable [a] -- Defined in Data.Hashable
  instance [overlap ok] Hashable String
    -- Defined at Hashable64.hs:70:9-23
```

#### Edit 2

Any other solutions to this specific problem are welcome. A good solution might provide insight into this overlapping instances problem.

Comment: Ah, yes, I didn't realize exactly how the instances were working here. I've edited my answer to explain better.

Comment: ghci tells me that "instance Hashable64 a => Hashable a" requires UndecidableInstances.  This is only a smart idea if you are editing the module in which Hashable is defined.

Comment: @Chris Kuklewicz: `UndecidableInstances` isn't really a big deal for something like that. The termination checker for instance resolutions is absurdly paranoid and it's actually pretty difficult to do anything weird that way. Simple "class synonyms" like this one will, at worst, result in overflowing the stack used for resolving instances and getting an easily-diagnosed compiler error.

Comment: As camccann said, but slightly rephrased: what you want is to override an implementation of `Hashable String` in the standard library with another implementation.  Unfortunately I do not think that it is currently possible with GHC without modifying the standard library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sort of situation is handled by [GHC's OverlappingInstances extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-overlap). Roughly speaking, this extension allows instances to coexist despite the existence of some type(s) to which both could apply. For such types, GHC will select the "most specific" instance, which is a little fuzzy in some cases but usually does what you'd want it to.

This sort of situation, where you have one or more specialized instances and a single catch-all `instance Foo a` as the "default", usually works pretty well.

The main stumbling blocks to be aware of with overlapping instances are:

- If something forces GHC to select an instance on a polymorphic type that's ambiguous, it will refuse with potentially cryptic compiler errors
- The context of an instance is ignored until *after* it's been selected, so don't try to distinguish between instances that way; there are workarounds but they're annoying.

The latter point would be relevant here if, for example, you have a list of some type that's not an instance of `Hashable64`; GHC will select the more specific second instance, then fail because of the context, even if the full type (the list, not the element type) *is* an instance of `Hashable64` and thus would work with the first, generic instance.

---

**Edit**: Oh, I see, I misinterpreted the situation slightly, regarding where the instances are coming from. Quoth the GHC User's Guide:

> The willingness to be overlapped or incoherent is a property of the *instance declaration* itself (...). Neither flag is required in a module that imports and uses the instance declaration.
>
> (...)
>
> These rules make it possible for a library author to design a library that relies on overlapping instances without the library client having to know.
>
> If an instance declaration is compiled without `-XOverlappingInstances`, then that instance can never be overlapped. This could perhaps be inconvenient. (...) We are interested to receive feedback on these points.

...in other words, overlapping is only allowed if the *less* specific instance was built with `OverlappingInstances` enabled, which the instance for `Hashable [a]` was not. So your instance for `Hashable a` is allowed, but one for `Hashable [Char]` fails, as observed.

This is a tidy illustration of why the User's Guide finds the current rules unsatisfactory (other rules would have their own problems, so it's not clear what the best approach, if any, would be).

Back in the here-and-now, you have multiple options, which are slightly less convenient than what you'd hoped for. Off the top of my head:

- **Alternate class**: Define your equivalent of the `Hashable` class, write the overlapped instances you want, and use generic instances with `Hashable` in the context to fall back to the original as needed. This is problematic if you're using another library that expects `Hashable` instances, rather than pre-hashed values or an explicit hash function.
- **Type wrapper**: `newtype` wrappers are something of a "standard" way to disambiguate instances (c.f. `Monoid`). By using such a wrapper around your values, you'll be able to write whatever instances you please because none of the pre-defined instances will match. This becomes problematic if you have a lot of functions that would need to wrap/unwrap the newtype, though keep in mind that you can define other instances (e.g., `Num`, `Show`, etc.) for the wrapper easily and there's no overhead at run time.

There are other, more arcane, workarounds, but I can't offer too much explicit guidance because which is the least awkward tends to be very situation-dependent.

It's worth noting that you're definitely pushing the edges of what can be sensibly expressed with type classes, so it's not surprising that things are awkward. It's not a very satisfying situation, but there's little you can do when constrained to adding instances for a class defined elsewhere.

Comment: yeah, I ended up writing the newtype wrapper... :( Thanks very much.

Comment: @gatoatigrado: Sorry I couldn't help more. You can smooth things over a bit for `newtype` wrappers using a couple techniques, though--e.g., for wrapping a specific type like `newtype WrapString = WS String` you can use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to create useful instances, and for generic wrappers like `newtype Wrap a = W a` you have trivial instances for `Functor` and `Applicative` that will let you lift functions through the wrapper.